# WordPress Echo Vimeo link to use as a video thumbnail via oembed

Tags: wordpress

Using the below code in WordPress i can reference a custom layersWP field to show a video as a thumbnail throughout the website. In the custom field is simply a Vimeo link. This is the only way it works.

The TEXT/Content in the WordPress post also contains the Vimeo link. & some description under it.

How would I replace "echo layers_post_featured_media" with an excerpt or the first 27 characters of the Wordpress post?

Thanks

- Display the Featured Thumbnail
  */
  echo layers_post_featured_media( array( 'postid' => get_the_ID(), 'wrap_class' => 'thumbnail push-bottom', 'size' => 'large' ) ); ?>

Comment: Have you tried **get_the_excerpt()**?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work and skips the vimeo link and inserts the description instead.